# colortbl and mdwtab

Tags: colortbl, mdwtools

There is an incompatibility between the packages `colortbl` and `mdwtab`.  The following document fails with LuaLaTex and the error `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdwtab}               % A
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}        % B
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{lightgray} % C
\begin{tabular}{l}
X\\
Y\footnote{Test}\\
Z\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I can comment out some of the lines to make it work.

- Remove lines B and C: Compiles, but no color
- Remove line A: Compiles, but no footnote, just the footnotemark.
- Switch order of line A and B: Compiles, but no color

Considering that `mdwtab` is a reimplementation of `array` tables, it is understandable that there are some issues.  However, it is the first I actually encountered.  The `mdwtab` manual mentions some adaptations that were necessary for some packages, all by the same author.  `colortbl` is just another one by that author (David Carlisle).

Is there an alternative package I can use to add colors to `mdwtab` tables?  It allows footnotes and I prefer its spacing for matrix environments.

Comment: I suppose you want me to look:-)

Comment: oops mdwtab doc says: `The preamble parsing works in a completely different way. There is a certain amount of compatibility provided, although it's heavily geared towar
keeping longtable happy and probably won't work with other packages.` `colortb` relies heavily on knowing the internal form of the preamble data so it can insert coloured panels in more or less sensible places, so if that's changed making colortbl work might be non trivial. Not impossible but not at this time of night:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That would be great! Thanks for looking into this.